# call function in epanet2.dll

Tags: delphi, delphi-xe3

I am converting code from Delphi 7 to XE3 for Epanet.  My issue is to do with the *char in a dll compiled in C.

The code within the dll is as follow:

```
int DLLEXPORT ENopen(char *f1, char *f2, char *f3)
/* Check that file names are not identical */
....
   if (strcomp(f1,f2) || strcomp(f1,f3) || strcomp(f2,f3))
   {
        writecon(FMT04);
        return(301);
   }
 ....
```

In delphi 7 is works correctly like this:

```
function ENopen(F1: PChar, F2 : PChar, F3 : PChar) : Integer; stdcall;
```

In XE3 301 is returned. I have tried to change PChar to PAnsiChar without any luck.

Comment: Please [edit] your question to show the Delphi code that is actually trying to call `ENopen` (including any variable definitions and assignments). Without seeing that, it's impossible to answer your question, because we have no way of knowing what any of the `strcomp` calls return. Also, please don't put tag information in your title. The tagging system here is very good at classifying things, and doesn't need help. :-) Please see [Should questions include "tags" in their titles?](http://meta.stackexchange.com/q/19190/172661). Thanks.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Basically your problem is that EPANET2.DLL is not Unicode.

First, change all PChar in EPANET2.PAS to PAnsiChar, like the following

```
function ENopen(F1: PAnsiChar, F2 : PAnsiChar, F3 : PAnsiChar) : Integer; stdcall;
```

Then change the arguments in the calls to EPANET2 entry points to use PAnsiChar.  Either of the following approaches will work since none of the entry points return strings.

-- Using strings --

```
var
  rc : integer;
  F1, F2, F2 : string;
…
  rc := ENopen(PAnsiChar(AnsiString(F1)), PAnsiChar(AnsiString(F2)),
    AnsiChar(AnsiString(F3)));
```

-— Using AnsiStrings --

```
var
  rc : integer;
  F1, F2, F2 : AnsiString;
…
  rc := ENopen(PAnsiChar(F1), PAnsiChar(F2), PAnsiChar(F3));
```